# Querying for a range of days and hours

Tags: php, sql, algorithm, range

I want to be able to calculate if something is within a range and return all results.

We have a table that has scheduled weekly activities. Each row of the table has an unique id, a day number, and an hour number.

```
id (auto int) | dayNumber (int from 0 to 6) | hourNumber (int from 0 to 23)
```

Based off of this table, we can determine when an event is supposed to occur on the schedule. For example, an entry of dayNumber=2 and hourNumber=3 would mean that an event is scheduled for Tuesday at 3 AM.

The part that I am finding difficult is that I need to run a query to get a range of scheduled events. So I will pass in a minimum dayNumber and hourNumber and a maximum dayNumber and hourNumber. My expected results will be every matching entry in that range.

The easier case is when the minimum is less than the maximum. For example (in PHP),

```
$minimumDayNumber = 1; $minimumHourNumber = 3;
$maximumDayNumber = 5; $maximumHourNumber = 6;
```

Where it gets more complicated is when I want to search the range from Saturday to Tuesday. For that, the variables would look something like this:
    $minimumDayNumber = 6; $minimumHourNumber = 3;
    $maximumDayNumber = 2; $maximumHourNumber = 6;

Using these inputs, I would need to query the database and find all entries within that range. There must be a good algorithm to either construct the query or a good query to do this fairly directly.

This seems easy on paper and I have done it with date ranges (actual date fields), but I just cannot get this to work correctly. Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if you need additional clarification.

Comment: Are you only storing a single weeks worth of data and clearing old data?

Comment: We are not 'logging' data here. We are only storing a weekly schedule. So all this table has is a list of scheduled times for the week for an event to occur.   
Longer Answer: There is an additional field in this table that I removed to simplify the question. It is a device ID. So this table serves the purpose of maintaining a schedule for hundreds of devices. The event is the same across all devices, so there is no field explaining what event needs to take place.

Comment: splitting your dates up into the seprate values makes for painful queries, e.g. you can't just do `between now and then`, and have to do `dayfield > $day and hourfield < $hour`, which then excludes a LOT of valid dates/times because of the oversimplistic comparison.

Comment: Just to be sure what you are looking for: Do you want ALL events within that range (E.g. From Saturday 3am - Tuesday 6am) or all events in that time for each day? (E.g. What's going on Saturday 3-6am, Sunday 3-6am, etc...) I'm currently assuming entire date range.

Comment: Jason, The first option is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
where (($maximumDayNumber > $minimumDayNumber and (dayNumber+hourNumber/24) >= ($minimumDayNumber+$minimumHourNumber/24) and (dayNumber+hourNumber/24) <= ($maximumDayNumber+$maximumHourNumber/24))
   or ($maximumDayNumber < $minimumDayNumber and ((dayNumber+hourNumber/24) <= ($minimumDayNumber+$minimumHourNumber/24) OR (dayNumber+hourNumber/24) >= ($maximumDayNumber+$maximumHourNumber/24))))
```

Comment: One more edit to count for the hours.  Given the data structure the day and hour really ought to be counted as a single unit so I added the hours as a fraction of the day and used that in the comparison.

Comment: also I'm not a php guy and I'm not sure of the database, but you could simplify this if yours allows for a between and a not between instead of all the <= >= stuff.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the answer because it gets everything into a sql statement. You have a slight logic error on the last line. Since we need numbers greater than min and numbers less than max to both show up, we need to parenthesize part of the statement and turn it into an 'or'. Also, there is a small $ type. I will post a comment next with the fix.

Comment: or ($maximumDayNumber < $minimumDayNumber and ( (dayNumber+hourNumber/24) <= $($minimumDayNumber+$minimumHourNumber/24) OR (dayNumber+hourNumber/24) >= ($maximumDayNumber+$maximumHourNumber/24))) ) ... If you fix that, I will accept your answer (I really like the divide by 24 solution. That works very well!)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
SELECT * FROM activities
WHERE IF( $minDayNum = $maxDayNum,
    ( dayNumber = $minDayNum AND hourNumber >= $minHourNum AND hourNumber <= $maxHourNum ),
    (
        IF( $minDayNum > $maxDayNum,
            ( dayNumber > $minDayNum AND dayNumber < $maxDayNum ),
            ( dayNumber > $minDayNum OR dayNumber < $maxDayNum )
        )
        OR ( dayNumber = $minDayNum AND hourNumber >= $minHourNum )
        OR ( dayNumber = $maxDayNum AND hourNumber <= $maxHourNum )
    )
)
```

Pardon the rubber duck:

- The first IF runs a check to see if the day is the same
- If so, a simple where clause will narrow down the hours of the day
- If not, we go to another if statement to see if we are traversing weeks
- The conditional pulls in all events *between* the range (Not *equal to*), conscious of week endings
- Last two OR conditions pull in the specific start/end day/time events

I didn't mock anything up, let me know how it works out.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I think your solution would work. I am upvoting your solution, but accepting another because I liked the simplicity of it. However, thanks for contributing. The logic seems sound.